# How to know if a function parameter value is the default in python

Tags: python, function, parameters, default-value

I have a function with some parameters that have default values, how can i know when one of those parameters values was changed without having to evaluate each of them individually?

This is the solution i have so far that works, i was just wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing it, it haves a list of the default values inside the function and evaluates if the parameters values have changed from default:

```py
def get_list_movies(self, session, *, limit='20', page='1', quality='All', minimun_rating='0', query_term='0', genre='All', 
                                                sort_by='date_added', order_by='desc', with_rt_ratings='False'):
        opt_attrs = locals()
        opt_attrs.pop('self')
        opt_attrs.pop('session')

        query_string = 'list_movies.json'
        url = ''.join([self.yts_api_url, query_string])
        params = {}
        default_values = ['20', '1', 'All', '0', '0', 'All', 'date_added', 'desc', 'False']

        for index, (k, v) in enumerate(opt_attrs.items()):
            if v != default_values[index]:
                params[k] = v
        print(params)
```

Comment: Suppose you have `def foo(x=3)`. Do you really care about the difference between `foo()` and `foo(3)`? Why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I take it that by *attribute* you mean default parameter value. You can't find this out directly. Instead, write your function to accept optional arguments as a list: `def f(p1, p2, *remainder):` or a dictionary: `def f(p1, p2, **remainder):` to see how the function was actually called, and write your own logic to apply defaults to what the caller passed in `remainder`.

Comment: What's the point of having so many different defaults if none of them are actually used? You could use `None` for all of them and simply build a dict of non-`None`-valued arguments.

Comment: @BoarGules i see, i think the dictionary option might work for my case. Thanks for the welcome, happy to be here.

Comment: "attribute" is the wrong word. Those are parameters

Comment: If you set default values to `None` in the function definition, then within the function set the values for all arguments that are `None`  the arguments that are `not None` are the ones the caller specified.

Answer (score 0):

here default value is assigned by using = that is keyword=value lets understand by different ways there is function jorge ALonso and there is 3 argument out of which 3 argument are assigned by default values so the function jorge alonso accept one argument that is require and other two are default that is optional  you got the answer i think if not then i can explain more